# I have to return some geographic data through a REST web-service instead of one with WMS or WFS protocol. What is the best data representation then?

Tags: rest, web-services, gis

Usually, when I can, I offer a layer to join on a `Geoserver`, for example, through a `WMS` or `WFS` service.
However, this time, its not the case. I am asked to provide a REST web-service method where among the attributes returned is a road (a line) that will sometimes interest the caller (and he will want to display it on a map), but most of the times he won't use it.

How should I return that line that depicts the road ? I will return a String, its quite sure, I think.
Should I encode it like `Postgis` does, for example ?
`LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1, 2 1, 2 2)` ?

What is the good practice when you have to return in a String attribute some geographical data, in a non-geographic web-service ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest GeoJSON format and MongoDB as a back end storage. Though you may wrap geometries from Postgis into GeoJSON either. It allows to store additional attributes and can be rendered by Google API or Bing API or QGIS at user front end.